# parsing white spaces in grok

Tags: logging, grok

I'm having some issue with white spaces in grok...

I have strings that look like this:

```
1491783364087   group-segmentation-service-master asdf-replica-sync-dev         5          55              55              0               consumer-1_ip-34-25-65.companya.com/10.34.25.65
```

I'm trying to parse them with grok with something like this:

```
%{NUMBER:poll_time} +%{WORD:consumer_group} +%{WORD:topic} +%{NUMBER:partition} +%{NUMBER:current_offset} +%{NUMBER:log_end_offset} +%{NUMBER:lag}
```

but I think I'm having issues accounting for the white spaces...

I've been trying to test various patterns in this:
http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

but haven't had much luck...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the grok token `%{SPACE}` to account for whitespaces. Also the token `%{WORD}` won't match your consumer group and topic, because the according regex is `\w` which translates to `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (alphanumeric with undescore). The closest thing to match it would be to use `%{NOSPACE}`.

Something like this should work:

```
%{NUMBER:poll_time}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:consumer_group}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:topic}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:partion}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:current_offset}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:log_end_offset}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:lag}
```